why am i getting error when i run the postman to know more about my get request to https server
This is the image of screen shot from postman which shows the error Postman is the app I am using to know more about  get, post requests to a https server that I have created .
Postman app is not giving me any details regarding my get request.
This is the error postman app shows some openssl error as shown in the image .
I think the issue is related to ssl certificate .
